# Best way to do this listing laravel with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

What is the best way to do this listing?

I would not want to do it that way "ugly".

```
/**
 * Get user indicateds
 * @return array|null
 */
static public function indicateds()
{
    $users = ModelUser::all();
    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        if( $user->financial->status_payment ) {
            $newArray[] = $user;
        }
    }
    return (isset($newArray) ? $newArray : null);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the collection's [`filter` method](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-filter):

```
return ModelUser::with('financial')
    ->get()
    ->filter(function($user) {
        return $user->financial->status_payment;
    });
```

I'm supposing you have defined the **financial** relation and you should eager load it as I did to improve the performance.

Answer (score -1):

One of the benefits to relationships is that you can use them to modify your queries, as well. So, instead of getting all users into a `Collection`, and then filtering that `Collection`, you can use the relationship to modify the query so that you only get the desired records in the first place. This will reduce the number of records returned from the database, as well as the number of model instances that get created. This will save you time and memory.

```
$users = ModelUser::with('financial')
    ->whereHas('financial', function($q) {
        // $q is the query for the financial relationship;
        return $q->where('status_payment', true);
    }
    ->get();
```

The `with()` is not required, but if you'll be accessing the `financial` relationship on the returned users, it is a good idea to eager load it.

The `whereHas()` is where the magic happens. It modifies the query so that it will only return users that have a related `financial` record that matches the conditions added by the closure used in the second parameter.

You can read more about it in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).